Oxyplot is not rendering the plot as fast i expected
Im taking as an input a large datasheet of a device , nearly 50.000 data every second .
Im trying to plot them as fast as possible ,the data send via websocket from a python script in my WPF app and the timer is set to 0.1 seconds in both python and WPF app.
The thing is that if i set them every second its working fine but if i set the timer less than 1 second its not working as expected .It have slower render times nearly every 5 seconds or nothing ..
Here are some parts of my code :
Python :
async def send_data(websocket):

    global min_data

    while True:

        if min_data is not None:

            data = {"min": min_data}

            try:

                await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))

            except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:

                print(f"Websocket connection closed: {e}")

        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

WPF:
 public Plot()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     InitializeRenderingLoop();
 }

 //Loop 
 private void InitializeRenderingLoop()
 {
     timer = new DispatcherTimer();
     timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
     timer.Tick += PlotView;
 }

 //Plot
 private async void PlotView(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (!isPaused)
     {
         try
         {
             var data = await GetDataFromSocketAsync("xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx", xxxx);
             if (data.Count == 0)
                 return;

             // Reuse the existing PlotModel
             if (SpectralPlot.Model == null)
             {
                 Debug.Write("========= Entered =========");
                 SpectralPlot.Model = new PlotModel
                 {
                     Title = "Data from Socket",
                     Background = OxyColors.Transparent,
                     TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                     PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.White
                 };

                 SpectralPlot.Model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
                 {
                     Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                     Title = "Wavelength",
                     TitleColor = OxyColors.White,
                     AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
                     TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                     StringFormat = "0.###",
                    
                 });

                 SpectralPlot.Model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
                 {
                     Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                     Title = "Units",
                     TitleColor = OxyColors.White,
                     AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
                     TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                     StringFormat = "0.###",
                     Maximum = 5
                 });

                 SpectralPlot.Model.Series.Add(new LineSeries
                 {
                     Title = "Data",
                     Color = OxyColors.White,
                     MarkerFill = OxyColors.White,
                     MarkerType = MarkerType.None,
                     LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
                     StrokeThickness = 2
                 });

                 SpectralPlot.Model.Series.Add(new LineSeries
                 {
                     Title = "Red Line",
                     Color = OxyColors.Red,
                     MarkerFill = OxyColors.Red,
                     MarkerType = MarkerType.None,
                     LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
                     StrokeThickness = 2,
                     
                 });

             }

             var series = SpectralPlot.Model.Series[0] as LineSeries;

             if (series != null)
             {
                 series.Points.Clear();
                 foreach (var point in data)
                 {
                     series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(point.X, point.Y));
                 }
             }

             SpectralPlot.Model.InvalidatePlot(true);
             DetectPeaks(data.Select(p => p.X).ToArray(), data.Select(p => p.Y).ToArray());
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         }
     }

 private async Task<List<PointData>> GetDataFromSocketAsync(string ipAddress, int port)
 {
     using var clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
     Uri uri;
     if (Uri.TryCreate($"ws://{ipAddress}:{port}", UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
     {
         await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None);
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.WriteLine("Invalid URI");
         return new List<PointData>();
     }

     var receiveBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
     var fullData = new StringBuilder();
     WebSocketReceiveResult result;

     do
     {
         result = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(receiveBuffer, CancellationToken.None);
         fullData.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer.Array, 0, result.Count));
     }
     while (!result.EndOfMessage);

     var json = fullData.ToString();
     Debug.WriteLine($"Received JSON data: {json}");

     try
     {
         var minValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MinValues>(json);
         var yData = minValues.min;
         return GetPointData(yData);
     }
     catch (JsonException ex)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine($"JsonException: {ex.Message}");
         Debug.WriteLine($"JSON data: {json}");
         return new List<PointData>();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
         return new List<PointData>();
     }
 }


If your library is not fast enough you may need to look for another library. If this is a real time view you may consider doing the rendering yourself, or use a simpler, lower level library. You could try ScottPlot, but I have not tried it myself.

Also consider if you can preprocess your data to keep point count down, There is probably not much point at drawing more lines than there are columns on the screen.

yiep the wavelength at least no needs to re-render, i only need the y axis , some guy in the forum wrote that oxyplot can handle more lines than mine so i dont think its the lib ... i think there is something else , maybe i have some wrong config with the websocket connection ?  i see many times that error : Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

I have used Oxyplot for some time, and it can really be quite slow if you try to throw to many points at it. Run a profiler if you are not sure about what it is that is actually taking time.

Ok found the problem ... i was using websockets , i moved in udp instead and cut off the messages until eaach of them be 65000 bytes...i think that was my error in first place .Anyways thanks maybe i will try ScottPlot also to see if i have less framedrops in the future to make it more optimized ,now it seems cool but maybe with ScottPlot makes faster the rendering proccess.
